# Mixing index and unindexed list elements in a form?

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

I have a handler like

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String get(@RequestParam List<Cmd> rows) {...}
```

And I use [Spring forms tags](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) to generate the inputs. So the JSP code

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(rows)}" >
    <form:input path="rows[${i}].name" />
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

generates

```
<input name="rows[0].name" value="...' />
```

This is all good, but I also want to allow the user to add rows dynamically, so template `input`s needs to be written. However, neither `name="rows.name"` nor `name="rows[].name"` works, so I have to write code to generate indexes, which is annoying.

Am I missing something here? Is there any better way to do this?

**Edit:**

BTW, I tried to use Javascript to generate `name="rows[n].name"` dynamically, but it becomes a problem if the user deletes a row in the middle. A code to rewrite all the indexes seems to be unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to insert new input. Spring generates following

```
<input name="rows[0].name" value="...' />
```

Now you want user to enter new value then your Javascript code should generate following line

```
<input name="rows[1].name" value="...' />
```

and suppose user wants one more value then,

```
<input name="rows[2].name" value="...' />
```

Remember to handle index while generating inputs using Javascript.

Comment: I eventually used this form with some server side processing to remove the "gaps" created by deleted entries.

Comment: In our project index was managed using Javascript. So you get null values for removed indexes or what?

Comment: Yes. The code previous crash when you delete rows from the middle. I have added code to pre-scan the list and remove the null values before it was passed on. Using javascript to manage indexes seems to be too complex for the simple form I was working on (it does not use Javascript anywhere exception to add/remove rows).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<form:input path="${rows[i].name}" />
```

instead of

```
<form:input path="rows[${i}].name" />
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work as `path` requires a path to an object in the request context not a value.